# Problemas al agregar a un array todos los elementos seleccionados (Reactjs)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input, checkbox

Estoy creando una lista de elementos que necesito ir insertando el valor seleccionado en un array cada vez que se marque un checkbox y en caso que se desmarque, este se elimine del array. Estoy intentando con un push pero algo esta fallando, ya que en algunos momentos pareciera que si se esta agregando y luego deja de funcionar.

Este es mi codigo:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const Checkbox = ({ state }) => {
  const arrayCheckbox = [];
  const [select, setSelect] = useState([]);
  const handleSelectAll = (e) => {
    const valueCheckbox = e.target.value;
    arrayCheckbox.push(valueCheckbox);
    setSelect(arrayCheckbox);
  };

  return (
      <div>
        {state.map((el, i) => {
          return (
            <div key={i}>
              <input type="checkbox" value={el} onChange={handleSelectAll} />
              {el}
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
  );
};

export default Checkbox;
```

Comment: Pero arrayCheckbox se resetea en cada en cada render... no será ese tu problema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Espero que te ayude, se puede hacer con una evaluación con método includes si es true ya está en el state y se elimina si es false lo agrega

```
    import React, { useState } from "react";

    const Checkbox = ({ state }) => {
        const state = ["uno", "dos", "tres"];

        const [select, setSelect] = useState([]);

        const handleSelectAll = ({ target }) => {
            const s = target.value;
            if (select.includes(s)) {
                setSelect(select.filter((sel) => sel !== s));
            } else {
                setSelect([...select, s]);
            }
        };

        console.log(select);


        return (
            <div>
                {state.map((el, i) => {
                    return (
                        <div key={i}>
                            <input type="checkbox" value={el} onChange={handleSelectAll} />
                            {el}
                        </div>
                    );
                })}
            </div>
        );
    };

    export default Checkbox;
```

Answer (score 1):

Tu problema está en que, con cada render, tu variable `arrayCheckbox` se reinicia. Intenta con esto:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const Checkbox = ({ state }) => {
  const [select, setSelect] = useState([]);

  const handleSelectAll = (e) => {
    const valueCheckbox = e.target.value;
    const copyArray = [...select];
    copyArray.push(valueCheckbox);
    setSelect(copyArray);
  };

  return (
      <div>
        {state.map((el, i) => {
          return (
            <div key={i}>
              <input type="checkbox" value={el} onChange={handleSelectAll} />
              {el}
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
  );
};

export default Checkbox;
```